# Using Ext JS with my HTML Files

Tags: html, json, extjs

I have an application uses Spring Security 3(has a Jackson Marshaller) runs on a Tomcat 7. I designed my application with Jquery and it runs well. I designed a login page with Ext JS and after successful login it redirects to index.html. However it gives an error and can't redirect because when server sends HTML file it comes into that function at Ext JS:

```
Ext.util.JSON = new (function(){
    ...
        doDecode = function(json){
            return eval("(" + json + ")");    
        },
    ...
```

I wants to render it as a JSON response and gives an error as usual. How to solve it?

**PS:** It gives that on Firebug:

```
syntax error

[Break On This Error] (<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is not returning valid JSON. Its look as if it is returning a HTML page (perhaps a friendly error page). If you follow the stack trace up its probably Ext.decode response.responseText (inspect this you'll see whats returned although not the best way)

First step would be to investigate the request in the Net panel in Firebug or Chrome, look at the request and response headers and content this will point you in the right direction. **Please please please** do not resolve this problem without first learning to use a client side browser debugger (Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools or even Safari) such as walking the stack on break on error, break on XHR, inspect the XHR headers and response etc.. not just watching the console window.

You might be able to fix this continuing blind but you'll pay heavily again next time.